# Does SharePoint Online add-in supports HostWebDialog="true" option in New Experience mode?

Tags: iframe, menu, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to make a SharePoint add-in work with SharePoint Online [New Experience](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-the-default-for-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) mode. The add-in adds a custom menu item that runs inside iframe (HostWebDialog="true") and works well with SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online Classic Experience mode:

```
<CustomAction Id="1237b974-6d89-4d20-b8ac-2b4ba8e21dce.MenuTest1"
                RegistrationType="List"
                RegistrationId="101"
                Location="EditControlBlock"
                Sequence="1"
                Title="Menu text"
                HostWebDialog="true"
                HostWebDialogHeight="280"
                HostWebDialogWidth="400">

    <UrlAction Url="~appWebUrl/Pages/MyPage.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={ItemId}&amp;SPListId={ListId}&amp;SPSource={Source}&amp;SPListURLDir={ListUrlDir}&amp;SPItemURL={ItemUrl}" />
  </CustomAction>
```

However with a new SharePoint Online New Experience it does not work. The menu item appears in context menu but the menu call is silently ignored. No JS errors or any messages are displayed.

Does SharePoint 2016 New Experience mode supports HostWebDialog="true" option in CustomAction?

Answer (score 2):

I had encountered this issue as well. I finally came across this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187523/add-in-targeting-modern-document-library-does-not-support-hostwebdialog-true) from August 2016 and it seems that it is not yet possible to open a page in a dialog box using the HostWebDialog property.